# Как мне в Vds Ubunty запустить под моим доменом мой сайт написанный на Goland?

Tags: ubuntu, golang, apache

Скачал на сервере Go и Apache по инструкции смотрел как это сделать, на go у меня только написанная маршрутизация, в файле так же есть шаблоны index.html style.css, такой вопрос возник как мне запустить мой файл на go чтоб он работал, а не обычный html (и под моим доменном)

```
 package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"

    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
)

func main() {

    //Маршрутизация
    http.Handle("/public/", http.StripPrefix("/public/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("./public/"))))
    router := mux.NewRouter()
    router.HandleFunc("/", HomeHandler)
    
    
    http.Handle("/", router)
    fmt.Println("Server is listening...")
    http.ListenAndServe(":8000", nil)
}

func HomeHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

    if r.Method == "POST" {

        err := r.ParseForm()

        if err != nil {
            log.Println(err)
        }

        name := r.FormValue("name_1")
        email := r.FormValue("mail_1")
        phone := r.FormValue("phone_1")
        message := r.FormValue("message_1")

        resp, err := http.Post("https://api.telegram.org/bot{token}/sendMessage?chat_id={chat_id}&text="+"Имя: "+name+" Почта: "+email+" Телефон: "+phone+" Сообщения: "+message+"!", "", nil)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
        }
        defer resp.Body.Close()

        fmt.Println(name, email, phone, message)

    } else {

        http.ServeFile(w, r, "index.html")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я в таком случае пользуюсь `nginx` в режиме обратного прокси.

1. Поднять файервол `ufw`:

   ```
   sudo ufw allow 22/tcp
   sudo ufw allow 80/tcp
   sudo ufw allow 443/tcp
   sudo ufw enable
   ```

   Очень важно разрешить доступ по SSH **до** того как будет включен файервол. В противном случае сервер будет доступен только с локальной консоли
2. Настроить nginx

   ```
   sudo vim /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/go-site.conf
   ```

   ```
   server {
      listen 80;

      server_name server.domain;
      add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;

      location / {
         # CORS preflight request
         if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
         add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
         add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';

         # Custom headers and headers various browsers *should* be OK with but aren't
         add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range';

         # Tell client that this pre-flight info is valid for 20 days
         add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 1728000;
         add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/plain; charset=utf-8';
         add_header 'Content-Length' 0;
         return 204;
         }
         if ($request_method = 'POST') {
         add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*' always;
         add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS' always;
         add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range' always;
         add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'Content-Length,Content-Range' always;
         }
         if ($request_method = 'GET') {
         add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*' always;
         add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS' always;
         add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range' always;
         add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'Content-Length,Content-Range' always;
         }
         proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
         proxy_set_header Host $host;
         proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      }
   }
   ```
3. Настроить DNS, чтобы ваш домен `server.domain` указывал на IP адрес вашего сервера.
4. Поднять бесплатный сертификатор `certbot`

   ```
   sudo apt install certbot python3-certbot-nginx
   ```
5. Установить бесплатный сертификат от Let's Encrypt

   ```
   sudo certbot --nginx -d server.domain
   ```

   На последнем шаге, когда сертбот предложит сделать переадресацию, нужно согласиться.
6. После того, так вы завершите разработку и захотите запустить в продакшн, стоит оформить приложение как сервис, чтобы автоматически стартовал при загрузке

   ```
   sudo vim /etc/systemd/system/my-go-server.service:
   ```

   ```
   [Unit]
   Description=My go server
   After=network.target
   StartLimitIntervalSec=0
   [Service]
   Type=simple
   Restart=always
   RestartSec=2
   User=my_user
   ExecStart=/path/to/server

   [Install]
   WantedBy=multi-user.target
   ```

   Запустить сервис

   ```
   sudo systemctl enable my-go-server
   sudo systemctl start my-go-server
   ```

Comment: Привет, спасибо  что ответили, получается мне nginx перейти ? DNS настроил, а вот в моем коде в go ничего не нужно менять?  а то я не много не понимаю честно говоря(

Comment: @ГорМанучарян да, в Go ничего не меняйте. Он будет выполняться внутри localhost на порту 8000, всё остальное будет делать nginx - обрабатывать HTTPS, CORS запросы и всё такое.

Comment: @ГорМанучарян ещё я подумал, что рано или поздно вы закончите разрабатывать ваше приложение и захотите добавить ваш сервер в автозапуск. Я добавил пункт 6 как сделать сервис в линуксе.

Comment: Спасибо большое, я попробую сделать, ну за ваши старание дай Бог вам здоровье

Comment: Извиняюсь, а где мне файлы go кинуть и статических файлов?